# C++: method of executing method call for each member in a struct

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have the following

```
struct X {
   typeA_t A;
   typeB_t B;
   ...
   typeZ_t Z; // Where some of these are Unions

   void do_something(){
      A.do_something();
      B.do_something();
      ...
      Z.do_something();
   }
};
```

Is there a way to, for disparate classes `A - Z`, me to shrink this to one or two lines?

If I use inheritance, I can get rid of the `A-Z`, but I can't get rid of the line count.

If you are down voting, please explain why.  If this is a fundamental issue with C++, that is not a good reason.

Comment: Seems to be an effort to avoid using an array (why?) An array of pointers to derived types from a base, with virtual functions.

Comment: @NeilButterworth right, I got that, but now I have doubled my overhead on construction, when getting rid of the lines is an issue of grammar, not computation.

Comment: "I have doubled my overhead on construction" - how so?

Comment: @NeilButterworth There may be virtually no objective difference in performance.  Visually, however, the for loop in the constructor introduces noise to the reader, when accomplishing this task with syntax removes all distractions, fullfilling the purpose of code clean-up.

Comment: @NeilButterworth but I think the array of pointers would be better for a situation where updating the members is necessary, as the tuple formation impacts that. So, when I get it working I'll add it for completeness, unless you want to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this would work, but instead of having 26 members of your class, you can have a tuple with 26 elements, with types specified as a template parameter list. It's then possible to iterate over the elements:

```
template <class... T>
struct generic_X {
    std::tuple<T...> data;
    void do_something() {
        do_something_helper(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
    }
    template <size_t... i>
    void do_something_helper(std::index_sequence<i...>) {
        (std::get<i...>(data).do_something(), ...);
    }
};
using X = generic_X<typeA_t, ..., typeZ_t>;
```

Comment: Awesome response.